# How to add HTML 5 audio tag to HTML document with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, html5-audio, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script to replace old flash audio/video elements with new HTML 5 audio/video elements using Beautiful Soup 4, however I am having difficulty creating an audio tag of the following format:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="../../files/audios/333/MP3File.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I tried playing around with this in the Python Interpreter but didn't get anywhere.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<html></html>")
>>> nextsoup = soup.new_tag("<audio controls></audio>")


>>> nextsoup
<<audio controls></audio>></<audio controls></audio>>
>>> nextsoup = soup.new_tag("audio")
>>> nextsoup
<audio></audio>

>>> nextsoup = soup.new_tag("audio")
>>> nextsoup = soup.new_tag("audio", "controls")
>>> nextsoup
<audio></audio>
>>> nextsoup["controls"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  line 958, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'controls'
>>> nextsoup["controls"] = ""
>>> nextsoup

<audio controls=""></audio>
```

So is there a way to go about adding "controls" to the audio or should I be using some other library? Also is there a way to specify a tag that does not have a closing tag, such as with the source tag?

I've also tried adding the elements as NavigableStrings and appending them where they should be but I've had trouble with the encoding, so I then tried specifying the encoding format - utf-8 then specifying soup.prettify(formatter=None) but the script keeps crashing with ascii errors...

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `controls` keyword argument and set the value to `None`:

```
>>> audio = soup.new_tag("audio", controls=None)
>>> audio.append(soup.new_tag("source", src="path", type="audio/mpeg"))
>>> soup.append(audio)
>>> print(audio.prettify())
<audio controls>
 <source src="path" type="audio/mpeg">
 </source>
</audio>
```